# Possible to make xcodebuild test show the compilation of the test

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

`xcodebuild -workspace aWorkspace -scheme aScheme test` both compiles and runs the tests associated with the scheme, but it doesn't show the compilation of the test suite. If there is a compilation error in a test source file, I only get `** TEST FAILED **` which certainly isn't very helpful when trying to develop in Vim.

Is there a way to make xcodebuild output the compilation of the test source files, just as with `xcodebuild build` shows the compilation of the regular source files?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem , just ensure you remove TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES from the xcodebuild parameters (doesn't look like you have that here).

and simply append 2>&1 to the end of the command. 
for some reason xcodebuild writes test output to stderr instead of stdout??

ie. do:

xcodebuild -workspace aWorkspace -scheme aScheme test 2>&1